# Video Conversion Tool for ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, multimedia, video-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best video converter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27864/best-video-converter)

Is there is there any video conversion tool in ubuntu? which supports all format of video file.