# Video converter for 3GP video?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-conversion

Are there any converters around that allow conversion of FLV/AVI/MP4 videos to mobile 3GP format? Preferably GUI based, but I haven't managed to find one yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of: [best video converter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27864/best-video-converter)

Comment: Not really. That was a generic question. I wanted converters capable of 3gp conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try WinFF.

> WinFF is a GUI for the command line video converter, FFMPEG. It will
>   convert most any video file that FFmpeg will convert. WinFF does
>   multiple files in multiple formats at one time. You can for example
>   convert mpeg's, flv's, and mov's, all into avi's all at once. WinFF is
>   available for Windows 95, 98 , ME, NT, XP, VISTA, and Debian, Ubuntu,
>   Redhat based GNU/Linux distributions.
>
> WinFF is open source and cross platform written in Free Pascal and
>   Lazarus. WinFF is published under the GNU public license. WinFF is
>   published without any warranty or suitability for any purpose.<sup>1</sup>

To Install WinFF [For Ubuntu](http://code.google.com/p/winff/wiki/UbuntuInstallation)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/)</sup>

Comment: I am going with this answer here because I also searched on the web a bit and could not find anything exact. And WinFF allows to configure presets and that can be done for 3GP I suppose although it does not come with a 3GP preset out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Now and then when I need to convert files with no fuss, I use [ConvertFiles.com](http://www.convertfiles.com/) online application.
It does what you want with a simple graphical interface, plus it's easy and free.

Comment: It does. I also use online-convert.com but these things have limit on maximum file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try [mobile media converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.php), [arista](http://www.transcoder.org/)

**How to install arista?**

From the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new terminal window)

`sudo apt-get -y install arista`

Mobile media converter you need download and install the .deb

**Please read, if you don't read, you never will learn.**

Answer (score 0):

You could try mobile media converter it has always worked for me you can get it [here](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverterDown.htm) it has a good User Interface and it has a vast array of presets to convert to.