# How do I convert a high quality video into a low quality one?

Tags: video, video-conversion

The computer is relatively old and underpowered, so video playback of high quality videos is jerky with any player.

How do I convert a high quality video to low quality video?

EDIT:
I tried `avconv -fs` to limit size and `-filter scale=iw/2:ih/2` to resize to 1/2; with output to `mp4` and `mpg`.
All 4 resulting files are not very good: `vlc` can play the video, but the quality is abysmal on the 1366x768 screen.
The source format is `Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 1920x800, 2030 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc`, `bitrate: 2127 kb/s` (as reported by `avconv`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [best video converter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27864/best-video-converter)

Comment: @sds, VLC has some advanced setting which you can try: Tools -> Preferences, then see with Input/Codec tab (like lowering post-processing ,...) and Video tab (try other output mode)

Comment: @sds, I think this question can counted as off-topic as it more related to VLC that can happen in any Linux distribution (or any OS). [What topics can I ask about here?](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). I don't know if we share same judgment sense. Also I did't flag it, because you could add more information about your case like Ubuntu version/desktop, graphics driver, hardware,...Like that, I may see it as a specific case that needs customized VLC setup or may be even not a problem in VLC itself.

Comment: @Sneetsher This question is perfectly on topic. sds: Please add the information requested in Sneetsher's comment.

Comment: @Danatela This question is asking specifically how to convert high quality video to low quality video, not just "how do I convert video to different formats". Not a duplicate.

Comment: Is it a particular vendor that has something in the binary blob driver to accelerate video decoding?  Do you have hardware decoding for anything in particular(h264 comes to mind)?  Is it just particular codecs that are high quality high compression?  You could re-encode them at a lower compression and improve playback that way without changing the quality at all or a little.  You could reduce the resolution.  Is it a flash streaming video or something you have locally?  Too many variables.  The question needs some clarification to be useful.

Comment: @hbdgaf: yes, the input format it h264; see edit

Comment: H264(High) is resource heavy.  End of story.  I'ld try changing compression instead of resolution first.  Not good enough, try a different codec with the same quality switches.  Finally if none of those produce usable output you're stuck with reducing resolution.

Comment: @hbdgaf: could you please be more specific? thanks!

Comment: I put all the necessary Google triggers in there.  For the moment I'm trying to let some lower rep user find this and produce a higher quality answer putting in wrench time than I have to spend.  If it stays stalled, I'll look in to a detailed answer instead of a comment that points in all the right directions.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience of this, however I would assume you should try [this](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/ConvertMe!?content=153277). You will have the ability to convert, change quality etc. Not what you're looking for? Try `sudo apt-get install transmageddon`

Answer (score 0):

Handbrake is a free video converter. There is a PPA on launchpad. (https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/handbrake-releases) It has options for data rate, audio data rate, resolution, frame-rate, and so on. It may take a little testing to figure out what your system can handle. Use a low data rate, and if needed degrade the resolution down.

Other Info:

480p (Typical DVD Resolution) = 4:3 Standard [640 high × 480 wide] or 16:9 Widescreen [852 high × 480 wide].

800 kbps constant bitrate 2 pass encoding H.264 is where I would start, but if you have a cpu below 1.5ghz then MPEG-4 might be better suited.