# How to remove audio from a specific time duration of a video

Tags: sound, video

Say I have a video of 5 minutes and I want to remove all audio from 1:00 to 2:00. Is this possible? If yes, how would I do this?

A question, [Remove audio from mp4 file](https://askubuntu.com/q/462769/184942) comes close to this but is closed as duplicate to [best video converter](https://askubuntu.com/q/27864/184942). The answers this question only mention various video converters but don't provide any actual guideline on removing audio (which is what I want).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With openshot is a matter of minutes --- you can install it from the standard repositories with `sudo apt-get install openshot` or using the software center.

Then

1. open the application
2. load the video
3. move it on one track
4. cut the video into subclips where you want to silence it (green arrows below)
5. click on the audio of the clip you want to silent.
6. write the new video in the format you want.

[image: openshot]

You have a very nice tutorial here: http://www.openshotusers.com/help/1.3/en/ar01s03.html

Comment: Note that it results in a drastic reduction of video quality for cases where input resolution is not matching any predefined outputs (in my case it is capture of scree from a mobile phone).

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu22.04, and found there is no openshot in its standard repository. But with changing the package name from openshot to openshot-qt, the installation could work: "sudo apt install openshot-qt". Even the installation is success, but I still couldn't run it in my Ubuntu22.04, and found the following errors: 
    self.timeline = TimelineWebView(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openshot_qt/windows/views/timeline_webview.py", line 3000, in __init__
    self.cache_renderer.setInterval(0.5 * 1000)
TypeError: setInterval(self, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'

Comment: packaged openshot is failing lately... you are probably better off, nowadays, by downloading and installing directly from their page: https://www.openshot.org/ (I am using the flatpack/snap version on my PC, but I am on Manjaro now, so no idea why it's failing on Ubuntu)