# VIdeo Converters for Ubuntu

Tags: video-conversion

What are good Video Converters available for ubuntu?

I mean at least they should be able do **Video ->Audio** Conversion. Something like Total Video Converter/ Freemake Video converter available for Windows.GUI applications are much preferred.

Comment: ffmpeg or avconv are best. no single command line tool has all the features of ffmpeg

Comment: dmMediaConverter
http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [best video converter](http://askubuntu.com/questions/27864/best-video-converter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

[4k Video to Mp3](http://itsfoss.com/extract-audio-video-ubuntu/) Best suit for me.

https://www.4kdownload.com/products/product-videotomp3

and the advance of this piece of app is it do multiple converts concurrently very fast.and it applies a random album art to the Mp3 captured from the video.

Answer (score 11):

I found a easy way using **VLC** media player. **winff** is also capable of doing the same conversion.

**Convert Video to Audio using VLC media Player.**

1). Open up VLC media player.then in menu bar select *Media* -> *Convert/Save* or Simply press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>.it will open up a window called "*open Media*".

2). And then in File selection area browse for the Video file which you want to convert using "*Add*" button.

3). Select "*Convert/Save*" button. it will pop up a window called "*Convert*".It will show the path to your selected video file as source file.

4). In settings area in front of *profile* label there have a small button to change settings.click that.

5). Under *Encapsulation* tab check out "*Wav*" option. then click *Audio Codec* tab.as Codec Select MP3.and give a suitable bit-rate,number of channels and sample Rate. after doing all the modification hit save.

6). then in *Convert* Window under *Destination* area click *Browse* button to give a file name and a path to the output file. in that opened up window select the path where you want to save the converted file and give a file name you want. after all hit save.

7). Click save in Convert Window. VLC will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**[dmMediaConverter](http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html)** is a crossplatform FFmpeg frontend (GUI) exposing some of its features. It is intended to be simple and easy to use but also to be able to achieve complex tasks. I have inspired myself from a lot of media converters like Handbrake, WinFF and MkvMergeGui. One feature was lacking from most of them, **video stream copy** (pass-through), that made me build this.

You can do a lot of stuff (***extract audio, crop, split, merge, burn subtitles, watermark, scale, bulk convert, etc***)  with it so check it out:

http://dmsimpleapps.blogspot.ro/2014/04/dmmediaconverter.html

Comment: that seems rich with loads of options.... (Y)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to go for HandBrake Video Convertor for Ubuntu. HandBrake is an open-source, GPL-licensed, multiplatform, multithreaded for standard or high quality conversions and tweak many basic and advanced options to improve your encodes.

File format: 
**It Supports MP4, MKV, AVI or OGM**

**Video:** MPEG-4 or H.264 (1 or 2 passes or constant quantizer/rate encoding)

**Audio:** AAC, MP3, Vorbis or AC-3 pass-through (supports encoding of several audio tracks)

[**Full Installation Guide**](https://webcheerz.com/best-video-converter-ubuntu/?utm_source=AskUbuntu&utm_medium=Link&utm_campaign=AskUbuntu)

Answer (score 1):

HandBrake
Is an open-source, multithreaded video transcoder: it converts digital media from one format to another, compressing the files in the process.

Arista
Is a simple to use multimedia transcoder for the GNOME Desktop. Choose an input file, DVD, or Video 4 Linux device, an output device, a preset and go. Features live encoding preview, automatic discovery.

dmMediaConverter is a crossplatform FFmpeg frontend (GUI) exposing some of its features. It is intended to be simple and easy to use but also to be able to achieve complex tasks.

Internet Friendly Media Encoder
Convert all your video to the latest and next generation video codec. The H.265 standard, able to produce same quality while reduce bandwidth up to 50%, which mean capable shrink half of original file size.

And more at: source:http://alternativeto.net/software/freemake-video-converter/?platform=linux

Comment: Thanks.but this is not providing a function to Video to Audio conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Try **Openshot**.

```
sudo apt-get install openshot
```

[image]

Here are the features of Openshot software:

```
   Support for many video, audio, and image formats (based on FFmpeg )

   Gnome integration (drag and drop support)

   Unlimited tracks / layers

   Clip resizing, scaling, trimming, snapping, and cutting

   Video transitions with real-time previews

   Compositing, image overlays, watermarks

   Title templates, title creation, sub-titles

   3D Animated Titles

   SVG friendly, to create and include vector titles and credits

   Scrolling motion picture credits

   Solid color clips (including alpha compositing )

   Support for Rotoscoping / Image sequences

   Advanced Timeline (including Drag & drop, scrolling, panning, zooming, and snapping)

   Frame stepping (key-mappings: J, K, and L keys)

   Video encoding (based on FFmpeg )

   Key Frame animation

   Digital zooming of video clips

   Speed changes on clips (slow motion etc)

   Custom transition lumas and masks

   Audio mixing and editing

   Presets for key frame animations and layout

   Ken Burns effect (artistic panning over an image)

   Digital video effects , including brightness, gamma, hue, greyscale, chroma key (bluescreen / greenscreen) , and over 20 other video effects

   OpenShot provides extensive editing and compositing features, and has been designed as a practical tool for working with high-definition video including HDV and AVCHD .
```

See here : [Main Web-site](http://www.openshot.org)

Comment: but also this not supply a function to convert video to audio.

Comment: It does: http://www.openshotusers.com/help/1.3/en/ar01s11.html#sect2_47

Comment: but it only mutes either Video or Audio. I want to extract Audio from the Video And save the audio in .mp3/.wav format.

Answer (score 1):

Parts of this answer comes from: [Software for converting mp4 files from 720p to 480p](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620680/software-for-converting-mp4-files-from-720p-to-480p/638695#638695)

---

[Mobile Media Converter by Miksoft](https://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.php) can be an easier way to do [transcoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Transcoding) tasks.

[image]

In the above screenshot we can see a queue of videos (one in this example) to be processed with the same customised properties which includes transcoding for one or more of the next:

### For Audio

1. Audio Bitrate
2. Audio Frequency
3. Audio Channels
4. Audio Codec

For Video

1. Video Bitrate
2. Video FPS
3. Video Size
4. Video Codec

Of course you will be in need to add (on your own) the proper codecs for which you wish transcoding your video files so that they will become available in the "Video Codec" Drop Down.

Please have a look at this answer in which I explain something related.

[How can I maximum compress video files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files/25532#25532)

Good luck!

Comment: I've now installed it but don't know how to run it. I've tried mmc and mobilemediaconverter from the command line (in Ubuntu). Oh, its available by right clicking on the file but I don't see a frame rate adjuster.